# macOS SwiftUI button foreground color changes after dark/light appearance change

Tags: button, swiftui

So I run the below code in playground and I see 2 buttons on light appearance, then I switch to dark mode. Both buttons update foreground color as part of SwiftUI framework to off-white. Then I tap on one button the foreground color on other button(s) changes to grey. See video attached below.
Using Xcode 13.1

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Current")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                Label("43.672490, -79.388932", systemImage: "location")
                    .frame(width: 175, alignment: .trailing)
            }
            HStack {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Location")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Travel")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

[Appearance change button issue video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m15X5.gif)

**Anyone faced this bug and have a solution or do I have to create a custom button and modify foreground color manually?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreground color does indeed not seem to adjust between light and dark modes properly. However, I was able to fix it using a color that takes the different appearances into account by adding it as a `.foregroundColor()` on the buttons:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let buttonTextColor = Color(.secondaryLabelColor)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Current")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                Label("43.672490, -79.388932", systemImage: "location")
                    .frame(width: 175, alignment: .trailing)
            }
            HStack {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Location")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
                .foregroundColor(buttonTextColor)
                Spacer()
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Travel")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
                .foregroundColor(buttonTextColor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is worthy of a bug report to Apple, IMHO.

Edit:

To exactly mimic the button, you need to use a custom `ButtonStyle`. I did not exactly match the colors, as you can do that yourself, but here is the gist of how it works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var buttonTextColor = Color(.labelColor)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Current")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                Label("43.672490, -79.388932", systemImage: "location")
                    .frame(width: 175, alignment: .trailing)
            }
            HStack {
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Location")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
                .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
                
                Spacer()
                Button {} label: {
                    Text(" Set Travel")
                        .frame(width: 95)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomButtonStyle : ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        if colorScheme == .light {
        configuration.label
                    .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color.white : Color.black)
                    .padding(3)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                    .fill(configuration.isPressed ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
                    )
        } else {
            configuration.label
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .padding(3)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                                        .fill(configuration.isPressed ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
                        )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be the way I'm trying to reproduce it, but I do not see this behavior on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 for what it's worth.

Comment: But does it update onTap. So in light mode foreground label color is black and onTap it turns white and on dark mode foreground label color is off white and onTap it stays off-white. The above .forgroundColor solution does not factor onTap change. To try the difference open System Pref > Security and Privacy and tap on lock icon (bottom left) and observe the behaviour of Cancel button. Thank you!

Comment: Answer updated.